# QProcessPrivate::execChild() failed to chdir

Tags: qt

I'm getting this odd runtime error in the Qt Creator console on OSX from Qt on a very simple demo app that looks like this:

`QProcessPrivate::execChild() failed to chdir to /Users/myname/9781590598313/paths.app/Contents/MacOS
Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?
/Users/myname/9781590598313/paths.app/Contents/MacOS/paths exited with code -1`

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QPainter>
#include <QPainterPath>
#include <QPixmap>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{

  QApplication app( argc, argv );

  QPixmap pixmap( 200, 200 );
  pixmap.fill( Qt::white );

  QPainterPath path;

  path.addEllipse( 80, 80, 80, 80 );

  path.moveTo( 120, 120 );
  path.lineTo( 120, 40 );
  path.arcTo( 40, 40, 160, 160, 90, 90 );
  path.lineTo( 120, 120 );

  QFont font = QApplication::font();
  font.setPixelSize( 40 );

  path.addText( 20, 180, font, "Path" );

  QPainter painter( &pixmap );
  painter.setRenderHint( QPainter::Antialiasing );

  painter.setPen( Qt::black );
  painter.setBrush( Qt::gray );

  painter.drawPath( path );

  //pixmap.save( "path.png" );

  return 0;
  }
```

I moved it to a different location on the hard drive, and I commented out the `save()` function, just in case somehow there were permissions issues happening, but no difference. I run Qt demos all the time out of these directories with no problems, can anyone spot the problem from this code?

There are no other cpp or header files in the project at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, not sure if the solution I found works for everyone, but here is what worked for me:

Select Projects and check the path that is given under Shadow build. Check if this is a valid path, and if not, change it to one that is. That's all.

Comment: (I realize that the question is 3 years old, but I figured that other people with the same question might land on this one)